# bootstrap angular collapse menu different from main menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so my title is terrible, but I need help with making my collapsed (mobile) navigation be different from the non-collapsed (desktop) menu.

I want the collapsed (mobile) menu to utilize the subjects array and not what is in the html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here's my html code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">    
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="tester collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left topmenu-left">
        <li ng-repeat="a in subjects"><a href="#">{{a}}</a><li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left topmenu-left">
       <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="team">Team</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right topmenu-right">
       <li><a ui-sref="home">Search Bar</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="home">Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

here's my controller:

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, $state)
{
  $scope.subjects = ['Math', 'Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Hindi', 'English'];
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem in your code: rendering is ok, it only needs proper link for each subject...

Comment: ya, so that's kind of what I'm trying to figure out. How to add the subjects array data to the collapsable menu and not the 'home' 'about' etc menu. I want two different menus basically, one for desktop view which is the 'home' etc nav list, and the subjects array for the mobile collapsable nav. I just can't figure out how to make the subjects array be a collapsable menu.

Comment: Why not to use a CSS @media query to hide the mobile collapse menu  when not collapsed? See this example http://plnkr.co/edit/y87L0wbSDubjlnrszgfI?p=info

Comment: Ya I was thinking about that, I just thought there was something more 'angular' to do this. Ok thanks, I'll up vote your response.